# Python - Beautifulsoup, differentiate parsed text inside of an html element by using internal tags

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So, I'm working on an html parser to extract some text data from a list of  and format it before giving an output. I have a title that I need to set as bold, and a description which I'll leave as it is. I've found myself stuck when I reached this situation:

```
<div class ="Content">
  <Strong>Title:</strong>
  description
</div>
```

As you can see the strings are actually already formatted but I can't seem to find a way to get the tags and the text out together.
What my script does kinda looks like:

```
article = "" #this is where I normally store all the formatted text, it's necessary that I get all the formatted text as one loooong string before I Output
temp1=""
temp2""
result = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Content"})
if(result!=none):
  x=0
  for(i in result.find("strong")):
    if(x==0):
      temp1 = "<strong>" + i.text + "</strong>"
      article += temp1
      x=1
    else:
      temp2 = i.nextSibling #I know this is wrong
      article += temp2
      x = 0
print(article)
```

It actually throws an AttributeError but it's a wrong one since the output is "Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?".

I also know I can't just use .nextSibling like that and I'm litterally losing it over something that looks so simple to solve...

what I need to get is: "**Title:** description"

Thanks in advance for any response.

---

I'm sorry if I couldn't explain really well what I'm trying to accomplish but that's kind of articulated; I actually need the data to generate a POST request to a CKEditor session so that it adds the text to the html page, but I need the text to be formatted in a certain way before uploading it. In this case I would need to get the element inside the  tags and format it in a certain way, then do the same with the description and print them one after the other, for example a request could look like:

```
http://server/upload.php?desc=<ul>%0D%0A%09<li><strong>Title%26nbsp%3B<%2strong>description<%2li><%2ul>
```

So that the result is:

- **Title1:** description

So what I need to do is to differentiate between the element inside the  tag and the one out of it using the tag itself as a refernce

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [meta-tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks  -- It is not that clear, what your issue is and your posted code is not throwing just this one error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

To select the `<strong>` use:

```
soup.select_one('div.Content strong')
```

and then to select its `nextSibling`:

```
strong.nextSibling
```

you my need to `strip` it to get rid of whitespaces, ....:

```
strong.nextSibling.strip()
```

---

### Just in case

You can use ANSI escape sequences to print something `bold`, ... but I am not sure, why you would do that. That is something should be improved in your question.

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class ="Content">
  <Strong>Title:</strong>
  description
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
text = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Content'}).get_text(strip=True).split(':')

print('\033[1m'+text[0]+': \033[0m'+ text[1])
```

**Output**

**Title:** description

Comment: I get what you're suggesting, but I need to use the </strong> tag as a selector since a lot of Titles seem to lack any kind of common endstring to refer to..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use htql for this.  Example:

```
text="""<div class ="Content">
   <Strong>Title:</strong>
   description
</div>"""

import htql
ret = htql.query(text, "<div>{ col1=<strong>:tx; col2=<strong>:xx &trim }")
# ret=[('Title:', 'description')]
```